# How to troubleshoot "docker: Error response from daemon: VolumeDriver.Mount: exit status 1%!(EXTRA []interface {}=[])."

Tags: docker, volume

After installing the docker plugin "vieux/sshfs", on fedora26 vm with 'Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6' and creating a volume via:

```
docker volume create -d vieux/sshfs -o sshcmd=root@192.168.1.2:/mnt/d_drive/docker/vieux_sshfs/jenkins/data \
-o IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
sshvolume_jenkins
```

I get the following when trying to create the container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name jenkins \
    --restart=always \
    -v sshvolume_jenkins:/var/jenkins_home \
    jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

...

```
docker: Error response from daemon: VolumeDriver.Mount: exit status 1%!(EXTRA []interface {}=[]).
```

I'm not sure if I've got a config wrong or missing or if this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue and here's how I resolved it.

1. I checked the volume with **docker volume inspect** command

```
"Options": {
            "map": "xyz/1000:@abc/@1000",
            "sourcePath": "./foo/bar/outgoing/"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
```

2. I found out the path was relative and the docker was not able to access it.
3. I changed the sourcePath from relative to absolute one

```
"Options": {
            "map": "xyz/1000:@abc/@1000",
            "sourcePath": "this/that/foo/bar/outgoing/"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
```

4. It worked once I did that.